# Why does the fingerprint sensor trigger the screen?

Tags: sensors, fingerprint

When I touch the fingerprint sensor while I watch YouTube in the app it activates the controls on YouTube, like I was tapping the screen. Somehow the YouTube app and maybe other apps listen to the event of the fingerprint sensor and reacts to it. This is very annoying to me since the fingerprint sensor is in an easy to reach place so it happens often. This is reproducible on different phones and android versions. Is there a way to disable this behavior somehow?

Comment: Is there a "swipe fingerprint" in settings that is enabled? On my Pixel 4a you can swipe to read notifications. Maybe something like that is enabled and is triggering the behavior?

Comment: Also mention the phones with Android version. It could be some setting specific to the OS

Comment: There's no option for this in settings. It seems to only trigger the event when the fingerprint is recognized or at least it successfully read the print. When I touch the sensor briefly or incompletely it does not trigger. I tried it on Android versions 9 and 12, it's the same. Only common factor is Mediatek CPU. In the video the first activation was touch on the screen, the rest were triggered by the sensor. [video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/GzlY5bXEHuM)

Comment: @ÁdámBozzay please mention the specific device model because each manufacturer can customize their own Android, thus doing different behaviors on different devices.

Comment: After watching the video, it looks like a hardware/software-related issue. Otherwise, this is just a guess, but it could also be related to the accessibility feature (e.g. MacroDroid Fingerprint Gesture Detector). You might want to check the Android's Accessibility settings.

Comment: I checked the accessibility settings, there's nothing relevant there. I don't think it's an "issue" since 2 completely different phones have the same behavior. But I'll check it on more. These 2 are noname chinese phones (no relation between the two) with completely stock android.

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of fingerprint is to wake up the screen (unlock screen lock).

fingerprint sensor is designed to unlock screen. it is (usually) only touched when screen is in locked state. But it does not harm to "unlock" screen each time fingerprint is detected, even it's already in unlocked state. From developers point of view there is no need for extra coding routine to ignore requests in unlock state. Like there is no need to ignore staircase light button while light is on.

Comment: Yes, when the screen is in sleep. But not when it's awake

Comment: my fingerprint sensor always wakes screen no matter what mode (I don't even have set any fingerprint, my device is secured with pin only)

Comment: While this answer may be true (that is: it wakes the screen), I don't think it's related to the question, which (according to the video on the comment) is like the screen being touched physically.

Comment: Since we don't know how YouTube is implemented, we don't know what event it subscribes to. But I would think that it does not specifically subscribe to the fingerprint sensor, because why would it? It's more likely that the fingerprint sensor triggers some more generic event (like wake up screen) and that's what YouTube reacts to. My question is why would the sensor generate an event like this when the screen is already awake?

Comment: *"why would the sensor generate an event like this when the screen is already awake?"* - question is why not? imagine you have a staircase light button that ignores all time increase requests until the light switched off

Comment: Contrary to a staircase light switch this does not really serve a purpose. You are saying that the user would tap the fingerprint sensor every now and then to keep the screen from going into sleep. I don't think that anybody does that, it's just not designed for that. Besides, the YouTube app already prevents the screen from going into sleep. It just does not make sense. And I'd be interested in what causes this behavior and how to prevent that, because it's annoying.

Comment: fingerprint sensor is designed to unlock screen. it is (usually) only touched when screen is in locked state. But it does not harm to unlock screen **each time** fingerprint is detected, even it's already in unlocked state. From developers point of view there is no need for extra coding routine to ignore requests in unlock state. Like there is no need to ignore staircase light button while light is on. I didn't say user would tap the fingerprint to keep screen awake - it's a side-effect. I think you got it ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/253899)

Comment: @jlehenbauer there are two questions. while it may not answer *"Is there a way to disable this behavior somehow?"* it actually represent an answer to *"Why does the fingerprint sensor trigger the screen?"* ;)

Comment: It doesn't relate to the behavior being experienced in this case though, only what the theoretical behavior could be surrounding this situation. If you're indicating your answer was based on a reading of the title rather than the question itself, then yes, we could consider changing the title to be more representative of the question being asked.